# How to add a EventReceiver for ALL users on sharepoint?

Tags: event-handlers

Does anybody know, how I can add an EventReciever to a List, so that it is called from ALL users that are doing action.

For example: I register an EventReceiver that catches the event "ItemAdded". Now, it must be called everytime when a user ads an Item. No matter what user it is.

I have already asked this on the MSDN forum, but there no one could help me.
[You can find the entry here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/sharepointdevelopment/thread/722674cb-91e4-49f7-8f7f-cd623a507f4a)

I'm unbelievable grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some other custom code which may be interfering?

Have you tried your EventReceiver in a brand, new web application?

Comment: Yes, I've set up 3 brand new Sharepoint Servers with SPS 2010, SPS 2007 & WSS 3.0

All servers are untouched by anything else, there is only my EventReceiver....

Comment: Is your class with the EventReceiver in in the GAC or the bin directory? Do you have any CAS policy in place for the class?

Comment: I've added the EventReceiver DLL to the GAC.
There is nothing in the class but this code:
public override void ItemAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties) {
            properties.Cancel = true;
            properties.ErrorMessage = "Called";
        }

Comment: What authentication method do your "other users" use?

Comment: I tried it with a local users.

Comment: Hey I found the problem xD It had nothing to do with Sharepoint.
It's too stupid to say it ;) But: Big Thanks for your help James!! Greetz

Comment: -1: Other people finding your question won't know how you fixed this, and we can never mark this question as answered until you tell us what the fix was! Please edit this with the real answer!